# Help me to identify the name of this part

Tags: espresso

[image]

This part is leaking. Can anybody please help me to identify the name of this part (see image)?
If it's not possible to get these parts anymore, can I use a different part which does the same job?

The espresso machine is a G3 Ferrari Lady C.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a [plastic compression fitting](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=plastic%20compression%20fittings&tbm=shop)

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. The thing is that my espresso machine is out of production, so I need a replacement part from another brand. Are these fittings generic?

Comment: Yes, your best bet would be to remove the part and take it to a hardware store. You could probably find something online, but it'd likely be easier to match if you're able to compare it.

Comment: I was planning to do that today :-)